# Modifying the result matrices of SVD so that $\Sigma$ is canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have the following matrix:

$ C'^* =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-0.0045 & -0.0059 & 0 \\
-0.0059 & -1.0000 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

I put it through the SVD algorithm and got the following matrices:

$U =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.0059 & 1.0000 & 0 \\
1.0000 & -0.0059 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1.0000 \end{array} \right),
 V =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-0.0059 & -1.0000 & 0 \\
-1.0000 & 0.0059 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1.0000 \end{array} \right)$
and finally:

$\Sigma =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.0045 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

The problem is that I would like $\Sigma$ to be in a canonical form, i.e:
$\Sigma =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$

I suppose I would need to change the matrices U and V in order to change $\Sigma$ to the canonical form since $C'^* = USV^{T}$. 
Does anyone have any clue how I could do it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to do? In an SVD the U and V matrices are orthogonal which is clearly not the case with your matrices. Moreover the "canonical" form of the diagonal matrix is with the singular values sorted in descending order (as you have written it); there is no way to rescale the diagonal entries arbitrarily without also changing U and V so that they are no longer orthogonal.

Comment: @user7530 yeah, they are orthogonal. U'*U = 0. V'*V = 0  You can of course scale the vectors comprising U and V so they no longer are unit length

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean here by canonical form? But it's trivial to do what you're asking...

Define matrix $M$:
$$ M = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{.0045}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$
That is, the diagonal entries are $\Sigma_{i,i}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ for all non-zero singular values $\Sigma_{i,i}$ and $1$ otherwise. Trivially, we have:

$$M\Sigma M = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] = \hat{\Sigma} $$

Also observe that $M$ is invertible hence we can write:
$$  U \Sigma V =  \underbrace{\left(UM^{-1}\right)}_{\hat{U}} \underbrace{M\Sigma M}_{\hat{\Sigma}} \underbrace{\left( M^{-1}V\right)}_{\hat{V}} $$

Observe that $\hat{U}$ and $\hat{V}$ still form an orthogonal basis, but the basis vectors are no longer of norm 1.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew Gunn: Unfortunately, the $\mathbf{M}$ transform, as currently written, does not leave us with a singular value decomposition because the domain matrices $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are no longer orthogonal. For example
$$
 \left( \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{M}^{-1} \right)^{*} \left( \mathbf{U} \, \mathbf{M}^{-1} \right) \ne \mathbf{I}_{3}.
$$

The question does invite more questions. Is $\Sigma_{1,1} = 1$? What is the canon behind this suggested form?
$$
\Sigma = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{I}_{2} & \mathbf{0} \\
 \mathbf{0}     & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
While we can only wonder at the mathematics motivating this problem, we can state some common understanding.

The Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra states that the matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, in finite dimension, resolves the domain as
$$
  \mathbb{C}^{n} = 
  \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
  \color{red}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)},
$$
and the codomain as
$$
  \mathbb{C}^{m} = 
  \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
  \color{red}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}.
$$
The singular value decomposition provides an orthonormal basis for each of these four fundamental subspaces. The $\color{blue}{range}$ spaces are aligned, and the singular values represent scaling factors between the spaces. Changing the singular factors changes the scaling between the spaces. We create a different problem.

As mentioned at the beginning, there is uncertainty about the first singular value being unity. My best guess at the SVD is
$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
with
$$
\mathbf{Y} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -59 \sqrt{\frac{2}{99115949+9955 \sqrt{99115949}}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9955}{2
   \sqrt{99115949}}} & 0 \\
 -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9955}{2 \sqrt{99115949}}} & -59 \sqrt{\frac{2}{99115949+9955
   \sqrt{99115949}}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\approx
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrc}
 -0.00592636 & 0.999982 & 0 \\
 -0.999982 & -0.00592636 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
$$
\mathbf{V} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9955}{2 \sqrt{99115949}}} & -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9955}{2
   \sqrt{99115949}}} & 0 \\
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9955}{2 \sqrt{99115949}}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9955}{2
   \sqrt{99115949}}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\approx
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rrc}
 0.00592636 & -0.999982 & 0 \\
 0.999982 & 0.00592636 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
$$
\Sigma =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{10045+\sqrt{99115949}}{20000} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{10045-\sqrt{99115949}}{20000} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\approx
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.00003 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.00446503 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right].
$$